# How can I switch off certain parts of my EU powered network/machines to conserve power?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm at quite an early stage of the game in terms of power generation but I have (possibly unwisely) started making Applied Energistics equipment as I really want to use it to manage the masses of storage I have not yet got a purpose for.

I am using an generator to charge 3 batboxes and connected to those I have a macerator, compressor and electric furnace via copper cable.

I also have hooked up my AE network to this but I don't want to use it all the time.

How can I switch certain parts of this powered electrical network on and off in order to only run certain things at certain times without having to break the copper wires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple, you just want a [Splitter cable](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Splitter_Cable).

> The Splitter Cable is a special cable which prevents EU from flowing through it when a redstone current is applied.

Comment: This works great although for others that follow, right now there seems to be a bug where you can't directly put a lever next to this. I covered the splitter in construction foam but running redstone 2 blocks out did the same thing. Thanks fredley!